# High consumer lag on Kafka Stream app that uses persistent key value store

Tags: java, performance, optimization, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am not getting as much throughput as I would think I should with my this Streams app that uses a state store and my consumer lag is going way up.  I'm wondering if there are any obvious configs that I could tweak or anything that could help optimize my throughput.

In my main I have this for properties:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "reading-stream");
    config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KAFKA_URL);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG, "52428800");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG, 0);

    final MyStream stream = new MyStream(config);
    stream.start();

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(stream::close));
}
```

In MyStream.start() is this code:

```
final Serde readingSerde = Utils.createSerde(Reading.class);
final Serde groupSerde = Utils.createSerde(Group.class);
final Serde checkStateSerde = Utils.createSerde(CheckState.class);
final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

final StoreBuilder storeSupplier =
    Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
        Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(STORE_STATE),
        Serdes.String(),
        checkStateSerde
    ).withLoggingEnabled(new HashMap());
builder.addStateStore(storeSupplier);

final KTable<String, Group> group = builder
    .table("group-topic",
        Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), groupSerde)
    );

final KStream<String, Reading> readings = builder
    .stream("reading-topic",
        Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), readingSerde)
            .withOffsetResetPolicy(Topology.AutoOffsetReset.LATEST));

readings
    .join(group,
        ....
    ).flatMap
        ....
        }).process(() -> new MyProcessor(), STORE_STATE);

final Topology topology = builder.build();
streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, this.config);
streams.start();
```

Also looking at using a different type of hard drive on AWS (right now using gp2)...

Any other ideas to help optimize this code?

Comment: A little unclear what this means "I am not getting as much throughput as I would think" -- how much do you get and how much do you expect per instance? In general, you should scale out your application by starting new instances to increase the overall throughput.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thanks, yeah I'm getting about 2,000 records processed a minute on one instance.  Honestly I'm not sure how much I should expect, but that number seemed low.  Tried to scale out to 10 partitions on 8 instances but that only resulted in 4-5,000 records processed per minute, and the instances all seem to process the records a different rates even though they are set up with the same resources

Comment: That is indeed pretty low. KS can do multiple tens of thousand for records per *second*... How big are your records in MB? Are you network/CPU/IO bound? Do you run on SSDs? What is your data ingestion rate?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax thanks for your responses.  We are bound on CPU a little bit. Currently using 2 cores of CPU out of the suggested 4.  Our ec2 instance is smaller than suggested for Kafka so we may try scaling that up to the suggested size, give Kafka more RAM and CPU and see what happens. 

We're currently using gp2 SSD, but I found a few places recommending HDD (st1) so we may try that as well.  Maybe that would help with read/writes to RocksDB...

Comment: also going to try to change flatMap to flapMapValues to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Not sure what suggestion you talk about. It sounds as if you run your Streams application on the same nodes as your brokers? This would be discouraged -- Streams applications should run on their own instances to avoid interfering with the brokers. We also have a sizing guide for memory/disk for Streams apps: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/sizing.html

Comment: Thank you for that link.

No, sorry if I'm not clear, we do have the streams applications instances separate from the broker instances.

Comment: We increased our CPU and memory on our kafka brokers and it seems to maybe have helped a bit, we're now at about 8,000 processed/min.

@MatthiasJ.Sax I'm reading conflicting information about whether HDD or SSD is better for Kafka streams apps that write to store.  We're thinking of trying HDD for the kafka brokers and SSD for the Kafka streams apps, does that seem good?

We have other stream apps instances that don't do any read or writes to the RocksDB store and they seem to keep up just fine

Comment: SSDs for Streams app is recommended if your use RocksDB because RocksDB is optimized for SSDs (not sure were you read that HDD is recommended for Streams apps? If this is a Confluent source, we need to fix it.) We also publishes couple of white papers containing recommendations/help to provision a Kafka cluster. Those should help, too: https://www.confluent.io/resources/

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments.  Here's a few examples of links: "Throughput Optimized HDD (st1) – Designed for high-throughput MapReduce, Kafka, ETL, log processing, and data warehouse workloads; $0.045 / gigabyte / month." https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ebs-update-new-cold-storage-and-throughput-options/

Comment: and another link: http://www.mammatustech.com/cloud-news/aws-elastic-block-store-ebs-getting-most-bang-for-your-money "Services like Kafka which writes to a transaction log in long streams, and databases which use log structured storage or an approximate of that using some sort of log structured merge tree (examples LevelDB, *RocksDB*, Cassandra) might do well with HDD EBS - Magnetic volumes...

...There is a good chance the HDDs would be better at Kafka due to the way Cassandra uses its version of log structured storage and updates and the way that Kafka does distributed logs"

Comment: For brokers, HDD might be ok. I thought HDD was recommended for Streams apps. But IIRC, we might actually recommend SDD for brokers too (not 100% sure --- please check the white papers).

Comment: We reset everything and changed to st1 HDD and it seems way better now.  Will continue to monitor it but so far it seems like it's made a big difference

Comment: As an update, it seems that we are decreasing lag at a rate of about 30,000/min with 10 instances and 10 partitions.  Much better!  For some reason some partitions perform better than others (the better partitions are reducing lag at a rate of about 4,000/min while the slower ones are about 1,0000/min) so we'll still be playing around with things, but it's in a much better spot.